# [AngularJS]: Add timeout delay on http GET

Tags: angularjs, http, timeout

How do you add a timeout when response is taking too long to respond? I have the following in my controller:

```
$payments.getShopStatus(data.siteUrl)
  .success(function(rdata, response) {
    // go to next step
  })
  .error(function(rdata, response) {
    // tell me something's wrong
    // go here if there is a three-second delay too
  });
```

In my factory, I have a simple http return to process the one above:

```
 getShopStatus: function(shop) {
   var me = this;
   var sUrl = String(shop);
   var req = {
     method: 'GET',
     url: sUrl
   };

   return $http(req);
 },
```

Where do I include a timeout/delay? I need to force it to fail after a three-second delay of no response.

Comment: You can add timeout inside your app config function. $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 3000;

Comment: This goes where in my functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global timeout configuration inside your main module app config function like below.

```
angular.module('mainModule', [/* dependent modules */]).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
}]);
```

or for individual call you need to pass timeout as a param in your $http call like below.

```
getShopStatus: function(shop) {
   var me = this;
   var sUrl = String(shop);       

   return $http.get(sUrl, {timeout: 5000});
 },
```

Comment: I tried adding {timeout: 5000} on my $http request, but it did not stopped after 5 seconds. It seems not to work, apparently.

Comment: I made a small tweak. I placed the `timeout` param in the `req` instead of the previous implementation above. It worked.